# Write a program to display a Position and all its related Job Applications

Tags: apex

```
public class positionwithjob {
    public static void posjob{
       list<position__C> pos=[select name,(select name from job_applications__r) from position__c];
        for(position__c p:pos)
        {  system.debug(p);}

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Shivang, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask]. What is your question? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

To give you a head start here, the Apex would more likely look like this:

```
public class positionwithjob {
    public list<position__c> getpositions() {
        return [
            select name, (select name from job_applications__r order by name)
            from position__c
            order by name
        ];
    }
}
```

and then in the Visualforce (if that is the UI you are using) you can use e.g.:

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!positions}" var="p">
    ...
</apex:dataTable>
```

but you will have to think about how you want the nested data to look and the parent rows to be selected.

But best you search for and invest time in following the relevant [Trailhead modules](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules) before you go much further. This site is intended to answer specific questions rather than offer full solutions for substantial problems.